# ros_vrpn_client Package not found

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have installed and setup ROS with below commands:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu trusty main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full
sudo rosdep init
sudo rosdep update
echo "source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
sudo apt-get install python-rosinstall
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-mavros ros-indigo-mavros-extras
```

When try to execute the command - **$ `rosrun ros_vrpn_client ros_vrpn_client __name:=Trackable1 _vrpn_server_ip:=192.168.2.11**`

I am getting below error like **ros_vrpn_client Package not found**

Please help me

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200515/ros_vrpn_client-package-not-found/) by [Nawaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21307/nawaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-01-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have not installed ros_vrpn_client.  It is pretty old and hasn't been released to the Debs.  You will need to compile from source.  I believe [this](https://github.com/damanfb/ros_vrpn_client) is the most update to date fork.  You could also try to use [mocap_optitrack](https://github.com/ros-drivers/mocap_optitrack) if working with a Optitrack setup.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2015-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nawaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21307/nawaz/) on 2015-01-08**:
Thanks for the quick reply.

I have installed ros_vrpn_client and compiled the source using install_vrpn.sh.
I have tried using mocap_optitrack package but still i am gettng Package mocap_optitrack_master not found.

Could you please explain me in brief, actual I am very new to this development.

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2015-01-08**:
The package name should me mocap_optitrack and you should use the launch file to load the parameters.